# Rails datetime_local_field help not pre filling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Job` model with a `first_booking_time` attribute. The `datetime_local_field` form helper doesn't pre fill the attribute stored on the `Job` instance.

```
# renders empty field even though job.first_booking_time is set
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= f.datetime_local_field :first_booking_time %>
<% end %>
```

However, if I use the `datetime_local_field_tag` helper and pass in the value, it works:

```
# pre fills what's in job.first_booking_time
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>    
  <%= datetime_local_field_tag 'job[first_booking_time]', @job.first_booking_time %>
<% end %>
```

How can I use the first syntax with the helper pre filling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<%= f.datetime_local_field :first_booking_time , :value => @job.first_booking_time %>
```

Comment: This works, thx. Why is the value attribute required? All other form helpers pre fill without it.

Comment: @migu Sorry. I don't know the reason, but specifying with `:value =>` always works :)

Comment: Weird, I had to change it to `f.datetime_local_field :first_booking_time, value: @job_create_form.first_booking_time.try(:strftime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` to get it working, with the normal format `2015-10-15 09:00:00 +1100` it wouldn't pre fill. Did you have the same issue?